# How do I execute logic before a page/component is generated in Nuxt3 (lifecycle)?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt3

I am attempting to execute logic to conditionally render content depending on the authentication status of the user. I would like to be able to execute this both on the server side and client side if there are changes.

How do I use component lifecycle hooks in Nuxt 3?

I tried something like this, but it is not working:

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>

    const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp();

    nuxtApp.hook('app:mounted', () => {
        console.log('BOOM!');
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, using the basic `v-if` statement is enough to achieve your needs. You don't need to use the life cycle hooks.

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
const userStatus = ref('authenticated')
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="userStatus === 'authenticated'">
            User is authenticated
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            User is not authenticated
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<style scoped lang="css"></style>
```

If you really want to use the life cycle hooks, you can. Like this.

Note: `onMounted` and `app:mounted` hook are client only.

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
const userStatus = ref<boolean | null>(null)
const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()
nuxtApp.hook('app:mounted', () => {
    userStatus.value = true
})
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="userStatus">
            User is authenticated
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            User is not authenticated
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<style scoped lang="css"></style>
```

Though this will trigger the same effects as using the `onMounted`

```js
const userStatus = ref<boolean | null>(null)
onMounted(() => {
    userStatus.value = true
})
```

I would recommend following the first example using the simple `v-if` statement as it supports SSR.

Comment: I figured out I can write logic directly within a script setup without having to use a hook. I was wanting to fetch a user profile and render the profile information depending on if the user is authenticated or not. I read somewhere that with script setup, the "created" lifecycle hook is not needed.

Comment: Yes, you can, and if you want to use it in a multiple pages, you can with middleware using the  if statement